# How to Display Modules in K2 Item Page

Tags: php, joomla

K2 Items aren't displaying modules. I'm tring to use "sidebaright" position.
This is the first time it happens.

Does anyone knows the procedure to fix it?

Modules are normal in all another pages.
The K2 item is assigned to a menu item as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you assigned your module to "all pages" in the module manager?

Comment: what template are you using? when you say K2 items you mean you assigned menu links to K2 items and these pages don't display modules?last point: are you shure the "sidebaright" position is available on the template you are using?

Comment: @chadocat I'm using template Departure for Joomla 3.0. The position is "sidebarright" and it's properly working in other pages..
Working with Article: http://evodiadigital.com.br/habitar/engenharia-servicos 
Not Working with K2: http://evodiadigital.com.br/habitar/engenharia-empresa